# SQL Advice - Aggregating data for specific cases

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Essentially I need to group unique product data into a single row when:

- The supplier sku matches
- The price for the products match (or) 1 of the product lines is equal to '0.00'

Here is a sample dataset set along with a working query for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm simply not entirely comfortable that this is the best way to perform this query.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
SupplierSKU VARCHAR(25),
Description VARCHAR(50),
Quantity VARCHAR(25),
Price VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT '123', 'APPLES', '15', '0.00'
INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT '124', 'ORANGES', '10', '15.34'
INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT '123', 'APPLES', '5', '27.40'
INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT '125', 'PLUMS', '67', '34.86'
INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT '124', 'ORANGES', '10', '15.78'
INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT '125', 'PLUMS', '3', '34.86'


SELECT SupplierSKU, Description, SUM(Quantity) AS [Quantity], MAX(Price) AS [Price]
FROM
(
    SELECT SupplierSKU, Description, SUM(CAST(Quantity AS INT)) AS [Quantity], (SELECT MAX(CAST(Price AS MONEY)) AS [Price] FROM @Test ti WHERE ti.SupplierSKU = t.SupplierSKU AND ti.Price = t.price AND ti.Price <> '0.00') AS [Price]
    FROM @Test t
    GROUP BY SupplierSKU, Description, Price
) pdata
GROUP BY pdata.SupplierSKU, pdata.Description
```

The desired results:

```
SupplierSKU Description Quantity    Price 
123         APPLES          20      27.40 
124         ORANGES         10      15.34
124         ORANGES         10      15.78  
125         PLUMS           70      34.86
```

Comment: Suppose there were another row for 'APPLES' with a price of '10.00'. Would you want the 15 '0.00' apples included with the '27.40' or the '10.00'? How would you decide? I don't think your current query even handles this case properly grouping by SKU/Price.

Comment: Thankfully the system will not produce data like this. The new row of 'APPLES' would have a different SupplierSKU.

Comment: should oranges return 10/15.78? or 20/15.78? you mention that prices should match (or 0)

Comment: Your stated objective does not match the desired result.  Or line 1 = 0.00.  Is line1 price? and if so why is that 0.00 apples not in you desired results.  Your stated objective does not include max or min but you have it in you sample code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Derek, yes there should be two lines of oranges in this case. Have updated and proven that my query is busted....

Comment: @Jesse: Back to my original question then. If there is now an entry for oranges with a 0.00 price, does it get grouped with 15.34 or 15.78?

Comment: Your current sql is giving the described result, in which way do you want it to change ?

Comment: @Joe: there were never be a case where there are 3 products with the same supplier sku within a result set.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I'm working solo at the moment and am so missing a team to work with. Was simply curious if any experts out there had an alternative suggestion

Comment: After you changed your expected result it made sense. So i posted 2 solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I repaired your own solution

```
SELECT SupplierSKU, Description, SUM(Quantity) AS [Quantity], MAX(cast(Price as money)) AS [Price] 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT SupplierSKU, Description, SUM(CAST(Quantity AS INT)) AS [Quantity], 
    (SELECT MAX(cast(PRICE as money)) from @test 
    where t.SupplierSKU = SupplierSKU and Description = t.Description and (t.price = '0.00' or t.price = price)) price
    FROM @Test t 
    GROUP BY SupplierSKU, Description , price
) pdata 
GROUP BY pdata.SupplierSKU, pdata.Description , price
```

Then I rewrote your solution to something more readable

```
SELECT suppliersku, description, sum(cast(quantity as int)) quantity, max(cast(price as money)) price FROM (
SELECT suppliersku, description, quantity, price FROM @test
WHERE price <> '0.00'
UNION ALL 
SELECT t1.suppliersku, t1.description, t1.quantity, max(t2.price)
FROM @test t1
join
@test t2 ON t1.SupplierSKU=t2.SupplierSKU and t1.Description = t2.Description
WHERE t1.price = '0.00'
GROUP BY t1.suppliersku, t1.description, t1.quantity
) a
GROUP BY suppliersku, description, price
```

You may notice i get the right quantity of apples (15+5 = 20)

Answer (score 2):

This should produce the "desired output" but the desired output is not consistent with the textual objective.  Why are quantity and price varchar.  This solution assumes you convert quantity to integer on the SQL table.

```
    SELECT SupplierSKU, Description, SUM(Quantity), P AS [Price]
    FROM @test 
    Where [Price] > 0 
    GROUP BY SupplierSKU, Description, Price
```

Comment: Thanks Balam. That is what I was looking for. Why are "quantity" and price "varchar" is a very good question and one that I would love to ask the architects of the system I'm currently within....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SupplierSKU, Description, SUM(Quantity) AS Qte, SUM(Price) AS Total
FROM @test t
GROUP BY SupplierSKU, Description
ORDER BY SupplierSKU
```

Does that gets you what you want?